# CLRS Exercise 6.4-5

Tags: algorithm-analysis

The question is as follows:
Show that when all elements are distinct, the best-case running time of HEAPSORT is $\Omega(n\lg n)$

https://walkccc.github.io/CLRS/Chap06/6.4/
This website provides a rather complicated analysis to this question, but the obvious answer that occurred to me was far simpler. Hoping if anyone can check if it is correct.

Since the height of a filled n-element tree is $\lfloor \lg n \rfloor$, the minimum number of swaps in one run of heapify would be the minimum distance from the root of the tree to a leaf node of the tree, i.e. min swaps $\geq \lfloor \lg n \rfloor - 1\geq \lg n - 2$.
Hence, the summation $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lg i - 2=\Theta(n\lg n)-\Theta(2n)=\Theta(n\lg n)$, which implies $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lg i - 2=\Omega(n\lg n)$.

Comment: I do not get it :```the minimum number of swaps in one run of heapify would be the minimum distance from the root of the tree to a leaf node of the tree```. Now height of a heap( almost complete binary tree) on $n$ nodes is $\lfloor lg (n) \rfloor$. The height of the root is the length of the *longest* path from root to a leaf. What I can say is that in all call of heapify on the root the number of comparisons $\leq \lfloor lg(n) \lfloor \leq lg(n)$ This is the utmost I can say. Now what is being considered as the *best case* required more analysis.

Comment: Probably you cannot just say what is the minimum number of swaps,like that. Note that after the build-heap all the smaller elements reside in leaves. We swap the max element at root with the right most leaf and it depends on how easily this small element (now at the root) again resides down, this in turn depends on the height of subtrees rooted at the left and right child of the root now with $(n-1)$ elements as one element is removed during the previous extract-max. This situation is quite tricky and not so simple I guess. This my opinion. It might differ from others.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589988/lower-bound-on-heapsort

Comment: Yup, you are right! There is no guarantee that the heapifying would mean swapping all the way down to the leaves. (and this is precisely what best-case considerations are about) For e.g., suppose we swap in an element, say 10 from a leaf of the right subtree. Suppose the left daughter of the root is 1000 and all the other elements of the left tree are less than 10. Suppose the right daughter of root is 999. Then in this case,  there would only be one swap when heapifying.